# Residue of a Holomorphic Form on $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$\omega = (z_{0}^{2} + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2})dz_{3} - z_{3}(z_{0}dz_{0} + z_{1}dz_{1} +z_{2}dz_{2})$$ be a $1$-holomorphic form in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$. The singular scheme is: $$ \mbox{Sing}(\omega) = \lbrace z_{3} = z_{0}^{2} + z_{1}^{2} + z_{2}^{2} = 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace p = [0:0:0:1] \rbrace$$ How to calculate the residue: $\mbox{Res}(\omega, p)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to learn how to calculate Grothendieck's residue from that $ 1 -form.

Comment: I think it is necessary to consider the open affine $U_{3} = \lbrace [z] \in \mathbb{P}^{3} ; z_{3} \neq 0 \rbrace$. In this open, the 1-form is written thus :  $$\omega = - xdx - ydy - zdz$$. I do not know how to proceed after this. Every help is welcome. Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean [Poincare residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_residue) that is integrating a closed (what if it is not ?) one-form $\omega$ over a basis of closed loops around the point (and take a cohomology class corresponding to it) ? $- xdx - ydy - zdz =- d(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is exact so it integrates to $0$

Comment: Theorem: Let $\varepsilon = (\varepsilon_{1}, \cdots, \varepsilon_{n})$, and consider the real $n$-cycle $\Gamma_{\varepsilon} = \lbrace z \in U : |f_{i}(z)| = \varepsilon_{i} , 1 \leq i \leq n \rbrace$ with orientation prescribed by the $n$-form $d\mbox{arg}f_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge d\mbox{arg}f_{n}$. If $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently close to zero, then: $$\mbox{Res}_{0}(g, f) =\left(   \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\right)^{n} \int_{\Gamma_{\varepsilon}} \dfrac{g dz_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dz_{n}}{f_{1} \cdots f_{n}}$$

Comment: How can I use the theorem above to calculate this residue? Where $ f = (f_{1}, \cdots f_{n}) : U \longrightarrow V$ be holomorphic map and $g \in O(U)$.